# ¿Por que no puedo hacer operaciones con datos importados?

Tags: python

Tengo un problema al ejecutar el siguiente codigo, la funcion del codigo es mostrar la edad de quien introduce el año, importando el año de datetime y almacenandolo en una var y posteriormente hacer la operacion año_nacimiento - año_actual.

```
from datetime import date

def calcular_edad():
    año = date.year
    año_nacimiento = int(input("En que año naciste: "))
    edad = año - año_nacimiento
    print("Tienes " + edad + " !")
calcular_edad()
```

al ejecutarlo me aparece este error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:/Users/HP27-101/PycharmProjects/Learn with moss/py.py", line 8, in
>
> calcular_edad()   File "C:/Users/HP27-101/PycharmProjects/Learn with moss/py.py", line 6, in calcular_edad
> edad = str(año_actual - año_nacimiento) TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'getset_descriptor' and 'int'

supongo que es por que no se pueden hacer operaciones entre ambos, tengo que hacer algo antes de almacenar el año en la variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema es que el objeto `date` que has importado no representa ninguna fecha concreta, por lo que intentar obtener su año mediante `date.year` no tiene mucho sentido.

La solución consiste en usar `date.today()` para obtener un objeto que representa la fecha actual, y entonces sí, sobre ese objeto, ya puedes usar `year`.

Por otro lado, la línea del `print()` también te dará error, pues intentas sumar cadenas como "Tienes" con enteros (`edad`). Lo correcto es separar por comas los elementos que quieras imprimir, o usar cadenas de formato:

```
from datetime import date

def calcular_edad():
    año = date.today().year
    año_nacimiento = int(input("En que año naciste: "))
    edad = año - año_nacimiento
    print("Tienes {}!".format(edad))

calcular_edad()
```

### Avanzado ¿por qué no daba error la línea `date.year`?

Si el error se debía a que `date` no es una fecha válida y por tanto `date.year` no tiene sentido ¿por qué no saltó el error en la línea en que hacías:

```
año = date.year
```

y en cambio salta más adelante cuando intentas restar `año - año_nacimiento`?

La razón es bastante técnica. Ocurre que la clase `date` sí que tiene un atributo llamado `year`, pero no es un entero, sino un *descriptor*. Es un método que será llamado cuando intentes acceder al año de un objeto concreto de tipo `date` (una fecha concreta). Ya que en este caso no tenemos el objeto concreto sino la clase, lo que obtienes al hacer `date.year` es el *descriptor* directamente, que no es ejecutado y no te retorna por tanto el entero que esperabas.

Al intentar operar con el descriptor te sale el error que observaste.

Comment: Gracias! especialmente por la explicacion avanzada.

Comment: en cuanto al print tambien seria posible convertir la variable a str con str(año - año_nacimiento) y despues si hacerlo como lo hice yo?

Comment: Si es posible, pero no es del todo correcto. La edad es en realidad (en concepto) un numero y no una cadena. Si quieres calcular que edad tendra el año proximo, o la diferencia de edades de dos personas, etc, y las tienes guardadas como cadenas, necesitarías convertirlas a enteros otra vez. Lo logico es tener la edad como entero y convertirla en cadena solo para imprimirla, y eso es lo que hace `.format()`